# Not able to output "total registrations today" count

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5

I am trying to output the count of total registrations today, registrations in the last 7 days, last 30 days.

All the other counts are output as expected. Except for registrations today.

```
$registration_summery = [
    'Registrations today'               => '+0 days',
    'Registrations in the last 7 Days'  => '-7 days',
    'Registrations in the last 15 Days' => '-15 days',
    'Registrations in the last 30 Days' => '-30 days',
    'Registrations in the last 6 month' => '-6 months',
    'Registrations in the last 1 year'  => '-1 Years'
];
$toReturn['registration_summery'][] = ['name' => 'Total Learners', 'value' => \DB::table('users')->where('users.role', 'student')->count()];
foreach ($registration_summery as $key => $value) {
    $tmp = \DB::table('users')->where('role', 'student')
        ->where('createdAt', '>=', strtotime("tomorrow", strtotime($value)) - 1)
        ->where('createdAt', '<=', strtotime("midnight"))
        ->count();
    $toReturn['registration_summery'][] = ['name' => $key, 'value' => $tmp];
}
```

No Errors, but the count shows 0

Comment: @rahul Thank you for your response. I tried the code you edited. Its still the same. Every other things work, except for registrations today.

Comment: Hello!!!!! it's not an answer!!!!! I just edited your question and nothing else. You will get answer below this if someone will.

Comment: @rahul oh. am sorry.

Comment: Check my answer Now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by substracting 23 hours more like this.

```
$registration_summery = [
    'Registrations today'               => '+0 days -23Hours',
   // rest data.....
```

Comment: No, that dint do anything.
When i change the code to     
'code'
    'Registrations today'               => 'now() days',
     // This outputs all registrations minus the registrations today.
'code'
what i mean is, if i have 100 registrations in total. and 5 registrations were made today. The output count shows 95

Comment: what hardcoded value you want for a range of dates as of now, so I can work on it accordingly?

Comment: Need to show the count of all the registration applications processed "today".
This is basically for a summary card on the dashboard. I am unable to point the problem, as the other values work fine.

Comment: from 2019-09-19 00:00:00 to until today's midnight right?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this.
Changed line 2 to -1 days.

```
$registration_summery = ['Registrations today' => '-1 days', 'Registrations in the last 7 Days'   => '-7 days',
```

and changed "midnight" to "tomorrow"

```
->where('createdAt', '<=', strtotime("tomorrow"))
```

Thank you @rahul for your help

Comment: am very sorry @rahul, i am new to Stack Overflow, and dont have much knowledge on things go on here. Couldnt figure out how to add code in your comments.